# How to clone a function pointer

Tags: rust

I have a structure with a field which is a function pointer. I want to implement the `Clone` trait for that struct, but I can't because function pointers can't be cloned if they have at least one parameter:

```
fn my_fn(s: &str) {
    println!("in my_fn {}", s);
}

type TypeFn = fn(s: &str);

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct {
    field: TypeFn
}

fn main() {
    let my_var = MyStruct{field: my_fn};
    let _ = my_var.clone();
}
```

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=49be325af14c6e3c071b&version=stable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that function pointers in general are not clonable, but that you actually have a function that is generic over the lifetime of the `&str`. For example if you replace the `&str` with `i32` your code will compile, because `i32` has no lifetimes. In your situation you need to make the lifetimes on the function pointer explicit:

```
type TypeFn<'a> = fn(s: &'a str);
```

This obviously bubbles up to the struct, too:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    field: TypeFn<'a>
}
```

This prevents the following kind of code:

```
let my_var = MyStruct{field: my_fn};
let s = String::new();
(my_var.field)(&s);
```

---

Actually the problem is that it's a bug. As shown in [@MattBrubeck 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33454743/1103681) Function pointers implement `Copy`. So you can just implement `Clone` manually by using the function pointer's `Copy` impl:

```
impl Clone for MyStruct {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        MyStruct {
            field: self.field,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: never mind me... The correct answer is it's a bug... I can't downvote my own post though ^^ and I cannot delete an answer that was accepted...

Comment: I used the method suggested by http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266154/1103681 . But feel free to change the accepted answer and leave a comment. Then I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Function pointers with references in their types don't implement `Clone` because of [issue #24000](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24000).  This means that you can't `#[derive(Clone)]` for types containing them; you have to implement it manually.

But function pointers *are* `Copy`, so you can `impl Copy` for your type and then use that to manually `impl Clone`:

```
impl Copy for MyStruct {}

impl Clone for MyStruct {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self { *self }
}
```

[Playpen link](http://is.gd/C2FwZO).

Comment: This is a great idea, unfortunately it doesn't work if you're using `Box<dyn Fn()>` since Box is not Copy. Looks like this might help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203307/how-do-i-create-a-trait-object-that-implements-fn-and-can-be-cloned-to-distinct