# How do I create a trait object that implements Fn and can be cloned to distinct objects?

Tags: rust

If I want a non-copyable type-erased (dynamically-typed) callable, that's

```rust
Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> ()>
```

If I want a ref-counted type-erased callable, that's (depending on whether I need thread-safety or not)

```rust
Rc<dyn Fn(i32) -> ()>
Arc<dyn Fn(i32) -> ()>
```

But here, the copies all refer to the same underlying memory - they're not distinct.

If I want *distinct* callable objects, how can I do that? `Box<T>` already implements `Clone` when `T` implements `Clone`, but `Fn` does not implement `Clone` so that doesn't apply here. Doing something like:

```rust
Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> () + Clone>
```

fails with:

```
error[E0225]: only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object
 --> src/main.rs:7:35
  |
7 | fn foo(f: Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> () + Clone>) {
  |                   -------------   ^^^^^ additional non-auto trait
  |                   |
  |                   first non-auto trait
  |
  = help: consider creating a new trait with all of these as super-traits and using that trait here instead: `trait NewTrait: Fn<(i32,)> + Clone {}`
  = note: auto-traits like `Send` and `Sync` are traits that have special properties; for more information on them, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#auto-traits>
```

The suggestion in the error doesn't work because of the spelling of `Fn`, but this:

```rust
trait CopyableFn: Fn(i32) -> () + Clone {}
Box<dyn CopyableFn>
```

By itself also doesn't work because:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `CopyableFn` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:7:11
  |
5 | trait CopyableFn: Fn(i32) -> () + Clone {}
  |       ----------                  ----- ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
  |       |
  |       this trait cannot be made into an object...
6 | 
7 | fn foo(f: Box<dyn CopyableFn>) {
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `CopyableFn` cannot be made into an object
```

Is there a way of creating a type object for `Fn` that is clonable such that the copies are distinct?

Comment: What is your goal in making the copies distinct?

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object). The problem is that adding `Clone` as a supertrait to `CopyableFn` makes it no longer object safe (`dyn CopyableFn` becomes invalid). The solution (`clone_box`) explained in that answer will solve your problem

Comment: Here is an example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=526fa5c419e5e1a1aa2f477833ca781e

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Yeah I saw that question, but I can't exactly add a base trait to `Fn`. And your example isn't really `Fn` either - it's a different kind of calling. `f_clone(42)` does not work, you have to write `f_clone.call(42)`.

Comment: *but `Fn` does not implement `Clone`* — [you sure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27883569/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster [This doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e00e7bbfc2f791aa344555d31a97fe78) though, which is how I thought things would work.

Comment: [Here is my example updated to use Fn](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9d8c628ee35065dcc177ed9ee394cc67). Does that work for you? If so, I think this should be marked as a duplicate

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Yep. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of having `CloneableFn` be a supertrait of `Clone`, implement a `clone_box` method that clones it into a box:

```rust
trait CloneableFn: Fn(i32) -> () {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn>
    where
        Self: 'a;
}
```

Since unsized types like `dyn CloneableFn` cannot be cloned (`Clone` requires `Sized`), there's little reason to have `Clone` as a supertrait here. However, having `Fn(i32) -> ()` as a supertrait allows the functions to be called as normal.

Then the `CloneableFn` can be implemented for all types that implement both `Fn(i32) -> ()` and `Clone`:

```rust
impl<F> CloneableFn for F
where
    F: Fn(i32) -> () + Clone,
{
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn>
    where
        Self: 'a,
    {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
```

Finally, `Box<dyn CloneableFn>` does not automatically implement `Clone` since `dyn CloneableFn` doesn't, so we can implement that ourselves:

```rust
impl<'a> Clone for Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        (**self).clone_box()
    }
}
```

With this, you can now clone `Box<dyn CloneableFn>` *and* call it as a regular function:

```rust
// let closure borrow some shared state
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicI32, Ordering};
let x = AtomicI32::new(0);

let f = |n| {
    println!("x = {}", x.fetch_add(n, Ordering::Relaxed));
};

let f: Box<dyn CloneableFn> = Box::new(f);
let g = f.clone();

f(3);
g(5);
f(7);
```

[Here's a full playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7c51a0725ee353ccc931c624c6e55e73)

This is related to [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30353462/155423), but in that case the targeted trait (`Animal`) can be altered to have a supertrait, while in this case that's not possible (since the targeted trait is `Fn(i32) -> ()`). In a way, it's the opposite approach: adding a trait of which the target is a supertrait instead of adding a supertrait to the target.